# How do I just remove one of the two legends in GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df     <- data.frame(iris)                   # iris dataset
pca    <- prcomp(df[,1:4], retx=T, scale.=T) # scaled pca [exclude species col]
scores <- pca$x[,1:3]                        # scores for first three PC's

# k-means clustering [assume 3 clusters]
km     <- kmeans(scores, centers=3, nstart=5)
ggdata <- data.frame(scores, Cluster=km$cluster, Species=df$Species)

# stat_ellipse is not part of the base ggplot package
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/master/R/stat-ellipse.R")


ggplot(ggdata) +
  geom_point(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=factor(Species)), size=5, shape=20) +
  stat_ellipse(aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,fill=factor(Species)),
               geom="polygon", level=0.95, alpha=0.2) +
  guides(color=guide_legend("Species"),fill=guide_legend("Cluster"))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

As stated in that picture how do I just remove 'Cluster' legend?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set your `fill` guide to "none"

```r
 ggplot(ggdata) +
   geom_point(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=factor(Species)), size=5, shape=20) +
     stat_ellipse(aes(x=PC1,y=PC2, fill=factor(Species)),
                                 geom="polygon", level=0.95, alpha=0.2)+
      guides(color=guide_legend("Species"), fill = "none")
```

---

Edit: 20221129 - changed `scale = FALSE` to `scale = "none"`, as per:

> The `<scale>` argument of `guides()` cannot be `FALSE`. Use "none" instead as of ggplot2
> 3.3.4.

Comment: The use of <scale>=FALSE is now deprecated, so the current syntax is: ggplot(ggdata) +
    geom_point(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=factor(Species)), size=5, shape=20) +
    stat_ellipse(aes(x=PC1,y=PC2, fill=factor(Species)),
                             geom="polygon", level=0.95, alpha=0.2)+
    guides(color=guide_legend("Species"), fill = "none")